# not all parms get parsed with mod_rewrite, why?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Once again I have a problem with my mod_rewrite, my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w\d~%.:_\-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+) /news?id=$1
RewriteRule ^contact/([0-9]+) /contact?do=$1
RewriteRule ^account/([a-zA-Z]+) /account?action=$1
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-zA-Z]+) /admin?action=$1
```

They all work, but it does not parse the parms afterwords?
i.e
www.domain.com/account/settings
works as I want it to, but if there is more $_GET parms in the URL, then it doesn't get parsed.
i.e 
www.domain.com/account/settings?parm=value 
doesn't work, the last parm doesn't get parsed to the server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `QSA` flag in your rules. `QSA (Query String Append)` flag appends existing query parameter while adding new ones.

Your converted rules:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/?$ /news?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^contact/([0-9]+)/?$ /contact?do=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^account/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /account?action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /admin?action=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w\d~%.:_\-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)